# Replace a line with another content using sed and parallel for a big file

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, gnu-parallel

I have a big file (50G) and I would like to replace the lines starting with the content of variable `$i` with content of variable `$newline` using `parallel` command.

My script is given below

```
#!/bin/sh 
File="test.txt"
i="foo"
newline="helooooooo"

parallel -a $File -k --block 30M --pipe-part 'sed -i /^$i/d' $File
echo $newline >> $File
```

It's not working for me, just deleting the line only.

Comment: What's the idea here in using `parallel`, why not just use `sed` to do all this by itself?

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue is here:

```
'sed -i /^$i/d'
```

Try this:

```
"sed -i /^$i/d"
```

The variable `$i` cannot get expanded because it's wrapped in single quotes, switching these to double quotes allows Bash to expand them with your variable `$i`.